# install drivers - dependency conflict: ubuntu 64 bits

Tags: installation, drivers, setup, dependencies, glibc

I got the message from the system as follow:

```
# apt-get install build-essential
The package libc6 needs to be reinstalled, but I can´t find an archive for it.
```

It is running in Ubuntu 64bits on Mac Mini, and the these are the step to follow to allow the Broadcom Ethernet/wireless drivers to be installed. Yes, the desktop hasn't internet connection yet.

All comments and suggestions are welcome highly appreciated!